# Steering wheel becomes stiff intermittently

Tags: power-steering, steering-wheel, maxima, rack-and-pinion, power-steering-fluid

The steering wheel of my 2011 Maxima SV becomes stiff intermittently while driving. Sometimes it is smooth but usually it is stiff and hard to turn. The steering pump was replaced about 6 months but didn't help much. I put in 2 bottles of Lucas power steering fix fluid, and that didn't help. When I turn the steering wheel to the end and let go, it slowly returns to the original position, so I don't think it's the pump. Any way I can diagnose he rack?

Comment: What kind of car?   Make,  model,  year?

Comment: @mike65535 it's in the original question. 2011 Nissan Maxima SV

Answer (score 1):

if it's the rack and pinion, it will most likely leak fluid into the end-boots from over-pressure.  You may see fluid drippings over time.  It's also possible you have a seized ball joint.  That's easy for a mechanic to check.